# How this bitshift to build the number works?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I saw this method which is used for faster reading of positive value of Long.

```
public static long readLong(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    long n = 0;
    int c = in.read();
    while (c < 48 || c > 57) {
        c = in.read();
    }
    while (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
        n = (n<<3) + (n<<1) + (c-'0');
        c = in.read();
    }

    return n;
}
```

While I understand all of the part, what I'm not able to get is this:
bit shifting by odd number to 
build the number `n = (n<<3) + (n<<1) + (c-'0');`

Why ignore the 3rd bit and how it's able to build it?

If anyone of you could explain me in simple way, it would be very much helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Not that I have an explanation at hand; but well; in order to find one; I would start, sit down with paper and pencil ... and emulate manually what this code does. Might take a while, but probably one could learn a lot from doing that ;-)

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add

Answer (score 2):

`n << i` is `n * 2^i`. So,

```
(n<<3) + (n<<1) = (n * 2^3) + (n * 2^1) = n * (2^3 + 2^1) = n * 10
```

Basically, it means to shift the value of `n` one digit to the left.

Adding it with `c + '0'` means adding the last digit with the integer value of `c`.

Comment: It's probably an attempt to optimize multiplying by 10, because the person who wrote this code thinks that a couple of bit shifts and adds are faster than doing `n * 10`...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code,

```
while (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
             n = (n<<3) + (n<<1) + (c-'0');
             System.out.println(n);
             c = System.in.read();
         }
```

If I enter `123456`, it prints

```
1
12 // 1 * 10 + 2
123 // 12 * 10 + 3
1234 // 123 * 10 + 4
12345 // 1234 * 10 + 5
123456 // 12345 * 10 + 6
```

So what it basically does is making space at the units place for the next number by just multiplying it by `10` and adding the `int` value of the character.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

- (n<<3) means (n*8)
- (n<<1) means (n*2)
- (c-'0') gives you the character as int value

Together this means

```
n = n*10 + theNewDigit
```